# Is there a way to check for available ports in range in PHP?

Tags: php, range, port

I'm currently trying to figure out how to check for all available ports in the range 53000-53050. However, I cannot figure this out. I've tried out multiple responses, and in my case, I either got an error stating "(No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)" using localhost as the host, or didn't load the page at all. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of this? After you compile the list of available ports, something could use one of the ports and the list will be wrong.

Comment: You are more likely to receive a response if you post at least one of the solutions you have attempted - many users of the site will shy away from questions without code as they can often be simple 'code requests.'

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, please use fsockopen and getservbyport

```
<form method="post" >
    Domain/IP: 
    <input type="text" name="domain" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Scan" />
</form>
<br />
 
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['domain'])) {    
    //list of port numbers to scan

//   $ports = array(21, 22, 23, 25, 53, 80, 110, 1433, 3306);

/////////// Use this block to set start port and end port 

$ports=array();
$i=53000;

while ($i <=53050){
array_push($ports, $i);
$i++;
}

/////////// end block

    
    $results = array();
    foreach($ports as $port) {
        if($pf = @fsockopen($_POST['domain'], $port, $err, $err_string, 1)) {
            $results[$port] = true;
            fclose($pf);
        } else {
            $results[$port] = false;
        }
    }
 
    foreach($results as $port=>$val)    {
        $prot = getservbyport($port,"tcp");
                echo "Port $port ($prot): ";
        if($val) {
            echo "<span style=\"color:green\">OK</span><br/>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<span style=\"color:red\">Inaccessible</span><br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and all of them are inaccessible. What I'm attempting to do is start a server and get an available port using PHP. PHP will check for the first available port in the range 53000-53050 and use that port.

Comment: if the result of the scan is inaccessible, it means it is available and you can start the server at that port （pls also allow connections of that port in your firewall settings)

Comment: Ooh, alright. Sorry, I'm quite new to PHP and only understand the basic stuff. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Short solution:

```
$host = 'stackoverflow.com';

$start = 53000;
$end = 53050;

for($port = $start; $port <= $end; $port++)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection)) {
        echo $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.' . PHP_EOL;
        fclose($connection);
    }  else {
        echo $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```